How to deal with error when pybind11 setuptools building
I am using pybind11 setuptools to build a python module(.pyd), but an error occurred:

executing :error: command 'C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual
Studio\2022\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.39.33519\bin\HostX86\x64\cl.exe'
failed with exit code 2

My code setup.py:
import os
from setuptools import setup,find_packages
from pybind11.setup_helpers import Pybind11Extension, build_ext

cpp_source_dir = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)),
                               "cpp_source")
serial_handler_path = os.path.join(cpp_source_dir, "serial_handler.cpp")
ext_modules = [
    Pybind11Extension(
        name="serial_handler",
        sources=[serial_handler_path],
    )
]

setup(cmdclass={"build_ext": build_ext}, ext_modules=ext_modules,packages=find_packages())

but it worked successfully on visual studio IDE when I used IDE button to build the .pyd file.
vs configures:[enter image description here](https://i.sstatic.net/OlsvYg61.jpg)[[enter image description here](https://i.sstatic.net/nHAnJRPN.jpg)](https://i.sstatic.net/lGCCVOC9.jpg)

I want to generate .pyd module by python pybind11 setuptools.
